# Java "variable can only be null at this location" with integer array

Tags: java, arrays, integer

I'm getting a `Null pointer access: The variable 'numbers' can only be null at this location` error from intellisense with the following code. (Errors marked)

```
public static int isOne(int incoming){
    String original = Integer.toString(incoming);
    int length = original.length();
    int i;
    int numbers[] = null;

    for(i = 0; i < length; i++){
        String worker = Character.toString(original.charAt(i));
        int workInt = Integer.parseInt(worker);
/* HERE */  numbers[i] = workInt;
        System.out.print(i + "=" + workInt + ","); /* this line just tests it */
    }

    int z;
    int sum = 0;
    int thisNumber = 0;

    for(z = 0; z < length; z++){
/* HERE */  thisNumber = numbers[z]; 
        thisNumber = thisNumber * thisNumber;
        sum = sum + thisNumber;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When running the code, the console gives an exception on the first error. LogCat gives nothing.

Intellisense give the suggestion of an `@suppress` for the two errors.

I really don't have a clue, but I think it might be at the point where I initialise 'numbers'.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Well, you don't really initialise `numbers`. You set it to null, which unsurprisingly causes a null pointer exception later on.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You assign `numbers` with `null` instead of assigning it with an array.

Change:

```
int numbers[] = null;
```

into

```
int[] numbers = new int[length];
```

Note that in java, declaring `int[] myVar` only allocates a reference to the array, and does not actually create the array object. In order to allocate the array itself, you use `new int[size]`, and assign the new object to the variable you want.

Answer (score 3):

You never initialize numbers.  You set it to null, and then you try to assign to numbers[i].  You need to set numbers to a new array

```
int[] numbers = new int[length];
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to initialize the size of your array like this:

```
int number = new int[length];
```

Another suggestion is to use the Java ArrayList which will allow more flexibility in creating your array. You won't need to initialize to a size and you can add to this array in your loop:

```
ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
int numbers[] = null;
```

to

```
int[] numbers = new int[length];
```

Answer (score 2):

...or more exactly, where you don't initialise `numbers`.

Arrays in Java must be declared (that part you have done) and initialised before any usage (that part you haven't). Instead of the `null` line, you should type:

int[] numbers = new int[length];

which creates a new and empty array of integers and `length` as its length.

By the way, it's more common to write `int[] numbers` that `int numbers[]`, because from the former, it's more obvious it is an array.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are setting the value to `null`. I think what you meant to do is

```
int numbers[] = new int[length];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right. The problem is that you are not initializing numbers

replace

int numbers[] = null;

with

int numbers[] = {1,2,3,4,5}

Answer (score 0):

this code is really strange, inefficient and buggy.

And useless while always returning 0

Try the following

```
public static int isOne(int incoming){
   return 0;
}
```

;-) or with the same calculations and a real, sorry int, return value

```
public static int isOne(int incoming){
   int sum = 0;
   int pos = 0;
   while (true) {
     int digit = incoming % 10;
     System.out.print(pos + "=" + digit + ","); /* reverse order!, this line just tests it */
     incoming /= 10;
     if (incoming == 0) break;
     sum += digit * digit;
     pos ++;
   }
   return sum;
}
```

Comment: the returning 0 is just so it returns something (I had it returning a boolean at first, and that made me have a return statement). Returning some is what it will do when I finish typing this comment ;)